# Comment Form Development Issue

Tags: theme-development, comment-form

I am new to wordpress theme development and I am trying to create a custom comment form. I read the documentation and I have a reach a point that I am happy with the layout but I have 2 issues with form's functionality.

First issue is when I am logged in to wordpress when I hit the "Post Comment" button, the message is not saved in MySQL. I believe that I am not doing something correctly while retrieving user input.

My second issue is that when I am logged out, I have some fields name and email which are not saved also for a reason and I face the below error: ***Error: Please fill the required fields (name, email).***

Attached you will find the code that I used to create the custom comment form. The function is called from single.php file which is the file that I created to display a single post.

Please note that I am asking your help not to resolve it for me, but just to learn and identify what I am doing wrong. Excuse my bad english. I am Greek!

```
function dck_custom_comment_form() {
//Declare Vars
$comment_author = 'Name *';
$comment_email = 'Email *';
$comment_body = 'Comment *';
$comment_cookies_1 = ' By commenting you accept the';
$comment_cookies_2 = ' Privacy Policy';
$commenter = wp_get_current_commenter();

$fields = array(
    //Author field
    'author' => '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-6"><div class="form-group"><input name="Name" id="name" placeholder="' . $comment_author .'" class="form-control" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '"></div></div>',
    //Email Field
    'email' => '<div class="col-md-6"><div class="form-group"><input name="Email" id="email" placeholder="' . $comment_email .'" class="form-control" type="email" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '"></div></div></div>',
    //Cookies
    'cookies' => '<div class="col-md-12"><div class="form-group"><input type="checkbox" required>' . $comment_cookies_1 . '<a href="' . get_privacy_policy_url() . '">' . $comment_cookies_2 . '</a></div></div>',
);

//Array
$comments_args = array(
    'fields' => $fields,
    'comment_field' => '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><div class="form-group"><textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="' . $comment_body .'" rows="4" aria-required="true" class="form-control"></textarea></div></div></div>',
    'comment_notes_after' => '',
    'title_reply' => 'Please Post Your Comments & Reviews',
    'label_submit' => 'Post Comment'
);
comment_form( $comments_args );}


function dck_reorder_comment_form_fields( $fields ) {
$comment_field = $fields['comment'];
$cookies = $fields['cookies'];
unset( $fields['comment'] );
unset( $fields['cookies'] );
$fields['comment'] = $comment_field;
$fields['cookies'] = $cookies;
return $fields;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the case. Problem here was on &fields variable declaration and also to 'comment_field' assignment. I had to change name fields with the correct ones.

Check code below:

```
function dck_custom_comment_form() {
   //Declare Vars
   $comment_author = 'Name *';
   $comment_email = 'Email *';
   $comment_body = 'Comment *';
   $comment_cookies_1 = ' By commenting you accept the';
   $comment_cookies_2 = ' Privacy Policy';
   $commenter = wp_get_current_commenter();

$fields = array(
    //Author field
    'author' => '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-6"><div class="form-group"><input name="author" id="name" placeholder="' . $comment_author .'" class="form-control" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '"></div></div>',
    //Email Field
    'email' => '<div class="col-md-6"><div class="form-group"><input name="email" id="email" placeholder="' . $comment_email .'" class="form-control" type="email" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '"></div></div></div>',
    //Cookies
    'cookies' => '<div class="col-md-12"><div class="form-group"><input type="checkbox" required>' . $comment_cookies_1 . '<a href="' . get_privacy_policy_url() . '">' . $comment_cookies_2 . '</a></div></div>',
);

//Array
$comments_args = array(
    'fields' => $fields,
    'comment_field' => '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><div class="form-group"><textarea name="comment" id="message" placeholder="' . $comment_body .'" rows="4" aria-required="true" class="form-control"></textarea></div></div></div>',
    'comment_notes_after' => '',
    'title_reply' => 'Please Post Your Comments & Reviews',
    'label_submit' => 'Post Comment'
);
comment_form( $comments_args );
  }
```

Thanks for your effort!

Comment: This does not work for me. I have added the code to the functions.php, but nothing happend. Comment form still looks the same as before. Did I miss something? And yeah, I am also new to WP development...